# Call pointer receiver method using address of variable

Tags: pointers, go

I am learning pointer receiver and notice that when I call the method using address of the variable I get error`./prog.go:21:10: v.Scale(10) used as value`

I can call the method using just the variable name or using the pointer. I am trying to understand why does Go complain when I call using the address of the variable `&v.Scale(10)` while the method is expecting pointer of `Vertex` type

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func (v *Vertex) Scale(f float64) {
    v.X = v.X * f
    v.Y = v.Y * f
}

func main() {
    v := Vertex{3, 4}
    var p *Vertex
    p=&v
    v.Scale(10)        //This works
    p.Scale(10)        //This works
    &v.Scale(10)       // This does not work
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
&v.Scale(10)
```

is the equivalent of

```
&(v.Scale(10))
```

The compiler complains because `v.Scale(10)` is used as a value.

Use this instead:

```
(&v).Scale(10)
```

Comment: Run it in the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/9PysFzRyUjs